I want to deploy a google script app project using python script, but getting unauthorized error
I am trying to deploy a google script app using python script as I want to automate it for a number of google script projects.
So I tried the following code below

credentials_data = {"token": "TOKEN_GENERATED_AFTER_LOGIN", "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "client_id": "XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", "client_secret": "XXXXX", "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments.readonly"], "expiry": "2024-04-03T17:38:59.298063Z"}
credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(credentials_data)
script_service = build('script', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

deployment_config = {
    'versionNumber': 1,
    'description': 'Initial deployment'
}

request = script_service.projects().deployments().create(
    body=deployment_config,
    scriptId=script_id
)

response = request.execute()

But the problem is I am getting this error
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"service": "script.googleapis.com",
"method": "google.apps.script.management.v1.DeploymentsService.ListDeployments"
}
}
]
}
}


When I tested your script with my values of credentials_data, I could not replicate your error CREDENTIALS_MISSING. I apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By the way, in the current stage, it seems that when script_service.projects().deployments().create(,,) is run, an error like Internal error encountered.. Ref Also I confirmed this error with the valid credential. So, when your credential is correct, this error might be able to be shown.

If you just create a new google script project and write some code in editor and use that script id for the code i have given, it should work. Also i think you should create the google script project from the same email id you are using credentials data
